# Flutter pub doesn't get dependencies

Tags: flutter, dart, version-control

I got a new project in flutter, and just wanted to add `flutter_svg` dependency. My pubspec.yaml

```
name: yo_soy_legal
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none'
version: 1.0.0+1
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.18.5 <3.0.0"
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter_svg: ^1.1.6
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

The error message is :

```
The current Dart SDK version is 2.15.0.

Because yo_soy_legal requires SDK version >=2.18.5 <3.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; Because yo_soy_legal requires SDK version >=2.18.5 <3.0.0, version solving failed.)
```

Flutter and Dart Versions:

```
Flutter 3.3.9 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision b8f7f1f986 (8 days ago) • 2022-11-23 06:43:51 +0900
Engine • revision 8f2221fbef
Tools • Dart 2.18.5 • DevTools 2.15.0
```

I already tried to reinstall flutter and change "enviroment sdk" value into pubspec file

Comment: can you please hit `dart --version` command on the terminal and share command output ?

Comment: Dart SDK version: 2.18.5 (stable) (Tue Nov 22 15:47:29 2022 +0000) on "windows_x64"

Comment: Verify the path of the dart SDK. Your error message says that the current version is 2.15.0, which indeed does not match the version requested. Perhaps you have 2 different SDK on your computer.

Comment: you are right, i got flutter upgraded but the release of flutter was old, just changed repository version to `latest`

Answer (score 0):

In most cases your cache must be cleared.
Run the following command in your project terminal.

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

If you are using vs-code sometime it gets dirty, you probably need to force reload.

> ctrl+shift+p

you'll see a popup, type in it

> Reload Windows

hit enter and vs-code should re-index the files in your project.

Comment: already tried, still got the same problem

Comment: Could be an issue with your installation, try out FVM it's very handy.

https://fvm.app/docs/getting_started/overview/